# Sorting a block subset from a sorted vector

Tags: matlab, sorting

I am working in Matlab and I have an unsorted vector **X**. I then extract a  random subset from **X** by taking random blocks and denote the subset as **Y**. For example, we could have **Y**=**X**([1:3, 10:12, 16:18]). The vector **Y** is extracted randomly each time in a for loop and needs to be sorted before further work is performed on it. Here's some pseudo code:

```
X=vector;
Z=zeros(1000,1);
for k=1:1000
   randomblocks=... % obtain the random blocks
   Y=X(randomblocks);
   Ysort=sort(Y);
   Z(k)=dosomething(Ysort);
end
```

This can get pretty slow due to the repeated sorting. My questions is is there some way that we can sort **X** before the for loop but extract the same points in some way within the for loop such that they come out sorted? I can't just take a random subset of the sorted version of **X** as sorting **X** ruins the block structure. I've tried a few ways but they've ended up being slower.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `loop` free approach like this:

```
%generate all random indices at once
idx = randomblocks(numel_block , 1000);
%generate all Ys at once, organized with blocks along the first dimension, iterations along the second
Y = reshape( X(idx) , [numel_block 1000]); 
%sort along the block dimension
Ysort = sort(Y,1);
```

Now depending on what `Z = dosomething(Ysort)` looks like this could go in it's own loop or something like `arrayfun()` may work out.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in the same number of total sorts though? The bottleneck in processing time has been the multiple calls of the sort function. It seems that this approach wouldn't fix that.

Comment: This approach would exchange multiple calls of the sort function with a single call of a sort function with opportunity for parallelism.  The overhead of 1000 function calls is significant, and defining the problem in a parallel way gives MATLAB the best opportunity to optimize.